# PHP catching undefined variable error

Tags: php, html, error-handling, try-catch

How do I go about catching an undefined variable error in PHP? I have a variable called $place that will only have a value if the user enters some details on another page, however if it has no value then it has an undefined variable error on the screen which I don't want.
I tried:

```
<?php try{ echo $place; }catch(Exception $e){echo 'No Place Set';}?>
```

but that doesn't work.
Any suggestions?

Comment: The question is fine, no editing needed because is clearly not a duplicate. This header talks about the usage of try-catch  or "catching" using exception handling. However the referred one has not even a single mention to this structure. The question is fine, no editing needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

undefined variables can be corrected by DEFINING them.

for instance:

`$place = '';` OR `$place = null;`

defines the variable. you will not get any error or warning.

Or use `if(isset($place)){}`

Answer (score 0):

just use [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to determine if the variable is set.

```
if(isset($place)){
    echo $place;
}else{
    echo 'No Place Set';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using try-catch for that? Just use `isset`

```
<?php 

if(isset($place)){
    echo $place;
} else {
    echo 'No Place Set';
}
```